# Visual Basic Usage of Input in TextBox

Tags: vb.net

Is there any way of taking the input that has being inserted to the textbox and use it 
e.g.: *textbox "Whats your name?" "*% Pain" -> *some code *output "How are you *% Pain ?"

Sorry for my terrible title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Dim textvar As String = [Textbox name].Text
```

Concatenate the output using the new variable